# How to Stop page autorefresh in Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I upload images to the server via ajax which are saved in the directory wwwroot.
After this operation page auto refreshing like "browser link".
How can I disable tracking for change in some directories in wwwroot ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are talking about the [Browser Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink) and not [Browser Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserSync) which is an extension in Visual Studio for ASP.NET projects.

Unfortunately, in either of them, there is no way you can disable it for specific directories. You can only disable them completely. Click on the link given above to learn more on that.